# Infinite-touchable numbers?

Tags: number-theory

Let *s*(*n*) be the Aliquot sum function ([A001065](http://oeis.org/A001065)), an [untouchable number](https://oeis.org/A005114) is a number not in the range of *s*, a “[2-untouchable number](https://oeis.org/A283152)” is a number in the range of *s* but not in the range of *s*^2, a “[3-untouchable number](https://oeis.org/A284147)” is a number in the range of *s*^2 but not in the range of *s*^3, etc. and an “infinite-touchable number” is a number in the range of *s*^*n* for all positive integers *n*, however, I cannot find the sequence of the infinite-touchable numbers in OEIS, thus what is the sequence of the infinite-touchable numbers? We can assume the strong version of Goldbach conjecture is true, i.e. every even number ≥ 8 are the sum of two *distinct* primes. I have run a PARI/GP program, but this program is slow, and I only find the set of the infinite-touchable <= 351 (for 352, my program run more than 48 hours with no result), these numbers are all [touchable numbers](https://oeis.org/A078923) <= 351 except 208, 250, 298.

(I know that 352 is infinite-touchable (assuming the strong version of the Goldbach conjecture), since a nonnegative integer *n* is infinite-touchable if and only if either there is an odd number !=5 whose aliquot sequence contains *n* or *n* is in an aliquot cycle (i.e. *n* is perfect, amicable, or sociable), and the aliquot sequence of 1231^2 (an odd number) is 1231^2, 1232, 1744, 1666, 1412, 1066, 698, 352, ..., which contains the number 352, but if we research all numbers likes this, it would be inefficient)

Comment: At the very least you want all the perfect, amicable and sociable numbers.

Comment: I know that all odd numbers (except 5) are infinite-touchable if the strong version of the Goldbach conjecture is true, but I use my program find that all numbers <= 351 which are not untouchable numbers, except 208, 250, and 298, are infinite-touchable if the strong version of the Goldbach conjecture is true.

Comment: Can untouchable numbers be obtained with PARI-A software  ?

Comment: Yes, just test whether there is a number k <= (n-1)^2 with s(k) = n, (n-1)^2 is sufficient. (In PARI/GP, use sigma(k)-k for the function s(k))

Comment: Do you mean "infinite-untouchable" ? Because I only see the definitiona of "untouchable" , "2-untouchable" and so on.

Comment: Yes, but I think the name “infinite-touchable” is better.

Comment: @Richard Chen I should have written PARI-AH :)